# TypeScript intersection types used in Diff type

Tags: typescript

In the definition of `Diff` type

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
```

How come the `& { [x: string]: never }` part doesn't "overwrite" the previous parts and make the resulting type simply `[x: string]: never` (considering `T & never => never`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason that interface that extends index signature with incompatible property is not allowed, but intersection is OK:

```
interface N {
    [n: string]: string; 
}

interface Bad  extends N { // error
    i: number;
}

type Good = N & {  // ok
    i: number;
}
```

The best explanation I could find for this is these two comments in two separate github issues:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13986

> Intersection is a bit interesting, it is a type operator that combine
>   types, and it is guaranteed to no cause errors. The compiler trusts
>   that these types exist. That is why you can have something like number
>   & string. The type says it is both types, `separate.a` is `string |
>   undefined` but `var a = "a"; separate[a]` is string.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18600

> At the point that you construct a self-contradictory type A, I don't
>   know how to determine what behavior is "expected" and what's not.

So now we have that `Diff` type in the wild and people are starting to use it, I think it's safe to assume that this one particular interpretation of how self-contradictory types behave should become the "expected" and "normal".

Comment: This is a good answer, but how do you actually use the type Good type? I am running into issues in declaring an instance of Good type.

Comment: You have to use type assertion because the type is self-contradictory, like this: `const g: Good = { i: 2 as string & number }`